# How to put value from getLongitude or getLatitude() intto EditText?

Tags: android

how to convert value from getLongitude() and getLatitude() to format that can be accepted by the EditText?

it works if i put them into Toast like this

```
String message = "Current Location \nLongitude: "+location.getLongitude()+"\nLatitude: "+location.getLatitude();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but if i put them into EditText like this, the application will stopped and error

```
tv_obj_long.setText(location.getLongitude());
tv_obj_lat.setText(location.getLatitude());
```

i think the format is wrong, i'm trying with Double.toString() but it still error

how to fix this?

thanks

this is my code on the button

```
btn_obj_useKor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
      showCurrentLocation();
   }
});
```

this is the function called by the button

```
public void showCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
                showToastStatus(location);
                tv_obj_long.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                tv_obj_lat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

this is the toast that works

```
public void showToastStatus(Location location){
        String message = "Current Location \nLongitude: "+location.getLongitude()+"\nLatitude: "+location.getLatitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

and this is my xml

```
<TextView
        android:text="Longitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_long"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <TextView
        android:text="Latitude"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/tv_obj_lat"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

help me guys -*_*-

Comment: what is the output of logcat?

Comment: @Stuti i didn't know about using the log

Comment: i added the another code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know the problem now,

I placed the declaration in wrong place

Look at this

```
public void showCurrentLocation() {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location != null) {
                showToastStatus(location);
                tv_obj_long.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                tv_obj_lat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terjadi Kesalahan dalam pengambilan koordinat", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
```

i added this code on second line

```
final TextView error_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.error_text);
```

and it works!!

i placed that code in onCreate before
T___T

Answer (score 2):

[getLongitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLongitude%28%29) and [getLatitude](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getLatitude%28%29) return double. So in roder to format the doubles into string you could use something like this.

```
String message = String.format("latitude = %f longitude = %f",location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
```

Answer (score 1):

That is because the parameter that the setText method expects is a string but what you are passing is a double. Double.toString() should work. Can you post the code snippet so that other developers here can see what might be wrong.

Or you may also do this.

```
tv_obj_long.setText("" + location.getLongitude());
```

That will convert it to string.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() * 1E6);
int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude() * 1E6);

GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lng);

tv_obj_long.setText("Latitude:  "+ String.valueOf(point.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6));
tv_obj_lat.setText("Longitude:  "+ String.valueOf(point.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6));
```

Comment: i think there is a not problem with convert value it is problem with your EditText. plz check your code carefully. did you define it properly or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
tv_obj_long.setText("" + location.getLongitude());
tv_obj_lat.setText("" + location.getLatitude());
```

The easiest way.

Another approach:

```
tv_obj_long.setText(String.ValueOf(location.getLongitude()));
tv_obj_lat.setText(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
```

The textView expects String as parameter in setText() method, you put INTEGER..it is normal to crash.

Answer (score 0):

```
tv_obj_long.setText(""+location.getLongitude());
tv_obj_lat.setText(""+location.getLatitude());

          Or

 String s = new String();
 s = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
```

replace your code with then given above code then you got your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the value into string
Try with the following code

```
tv_obj_long.setText(""+location.getLongitude());
tv_obj_lat.setText(""+location.getLatitude());
```